# Problems converting from pptx to pdf with unoconv

Tags: python, unoconv

I am using UNOCONV to convert pptx files to pdf. It works beautifully, but it prints the name of the slide on top, I haven't found a way to fix it.

Do you have any recommendations?

This is the code I am using:

```
# requirements
# sudo apt install unoconv
# pip install tqdm
# pip install glob
import glob
import tqdm
path = "<INPUT FOLDER>"
extension = "pptx"
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "/**/*.{}".format(extension), recursive=True)]
for f in tqdm.tqdm(files):
    command = "unoconv -f pdf \"{}\"".format(f)
    os.system(command)
```